# Что добавить в RESTful проект, чтобы видеть в браузере пользовательский интерфейс, а не JSON?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Я сделал первый guide с сайта Spring и вот что вышло:

```
package com.example.restService;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
package com.example.restService;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name",
                defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template,
                name));
    }
}
```

Если пройти в браузере по адресу `localhost:8080/greeting`, то представится JSON, а я хочу, чтобы был какой-то HTML и JavaScript, которые отобразят мой JSON в пользовательское представление, как это сделать ?

Comment: А где этот html и js который должны отображаться?

Comment: @JVic их нет. Я думал кто-нибудь предложит их и скажет где они должны быть (папка resources полагаю)

Comment: Ну вот там они и должны быть, только написаны вами. И ещё, restcontroller всегда возвращает JSON, для того что бы возвращало страницу используйте controller

Comment: @JVic про RestController знаю. Предложите пожалуйста свои HTML и CSS.

Comment: Вы меня просите написать за вас UI? Я не хочу этого делать, могу поделиться знаниями, но не делать за вас

Comment: @JVic я видел guide на сайте спринга https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/, там описано то что мне нужно, но только для стороннего RESTful сервиса. В этом guide'е всего 8 строк JavaScript'а. Почему-то у Spring куча каких-то разрозненных guide'ов и туториалов и нет одного полноценного туториала, как у Python'овского Django, где в одном простом проекте показаны и обработка форм и работа с субд и статика. Может вы поделитесь ссылкой на подобный полноценный туториал/проект ? Буду благодарен

Comment: @Антон - Spring + Angular - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web , простенькое приложение, но можно понять как все работает

Comment: @Антон Вот то что предлагает сам спринг https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic, там и работа с субд, и пользовательский интерфейс

Comment: @JVic спасибо, было бы это ещё и RESTful...

Answer (score 0):

Я поднимал Swagger UI ( статичный сайт опен сорс) на openApi спецификацию.

Comment: Сдаётся мне, он не это хочет...

Comment: @Qwertiy выбор делать ему, я навязать не смогу, не в моих силах